# Android how to set scrollview

Tags: android, xml

For my college I'm making an android app..
The xml code is:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/back">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_login"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="430dp"

        android:background="@drawable/oie_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="College name"
                android:textColor="@color/red1"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/desc"
                android:textColor="@color/purple2"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_style"
                    android:ems="10" 
                    android:hint="student name"
                    android:textColorHint="#7D0541"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_style"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:ems="10" 
                    android:hint="student roll no" 
                     android:textColorHint="#7D0541">


                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Press Here"
                     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_state"
                    android:textColor="#0000A0"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here,the 2 edit boxes and one button is there,I want to add a scrollview in there..But When I am adding its showing error every time..Hey guys can anyone tell me where is the problem..

Comment: "showing error every time." What is the error?

Comment: set wrap_content to match_parent..and when I add match_parent its creats a mess in my code

Comment: Where your want to add the scroll view? for whole lay out or what?

Comment: In between the 2 edit boxes and one button..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227779/scrollview-in-relativelayout-android/27227868?noredirect=1#comment42933548_27227868

Comment: Try my answer below, is that your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Paste your above line of code in between the scroll line of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

//Paste your xml code here

```
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/btnEdit"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/tvExtraCharge"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sackscontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_login"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="430dp"


        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="College name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
            <ScrollView 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"

                    android:ems="10" 
                    android:hint="student name"
                    android:textColorHint="#7D0541"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:ems="10" 
                    android:hint="student roll no" 
                    android:textColorHint="#7D0541">


                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Press Here"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#0000A0"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView as parent layout for linear_login and try to remove un-required inner LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/back">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/oie_transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="College name"
                android:textColor="@color/red1"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/desc"
                android:textColor="@color/purple2"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_style"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="student name"
                android:textColorHint="#7D0541"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="student roll no"
                android:textColorHint="#7D0541"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Press Here"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_state"
                android:textColor="#0000A0"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```